# Adding a file to a foobar playlist without switching to that playlist

Tags: foobar2000

My playlist creation process looks somewhat like that:

1. Open a new playlist
2. Filter nice music from my library ('Filter Results' playlist)
3. Drag a file from the filtered list to the new playlist
4. Switch back to the Filtered Results
5. Go to 3 and continue until the playlist is compiled

I'd like to get rid of the 4th stage (i.e not lose the filtered results focus) which is really tiresome.
Even better: use keyboard shortcut to add files to the playlist.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Right click on the tracks you want to copy, click "Collect". This appends the selected tracks to the clipboard. Repeat until all the desired tracks have been copied.
2. Paste them in the new playlist.

You may have to enable the "Collect" context menu in the Preferences (Display > Context Menu).

Comment: actually `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select any number of tracks you want then: right click > send selection > [your playlist name]

Answer (score -1):

You can also drag and drop the song to the title of your new playlist.

Comment: This is specifically what he wants to avoid.